# TFLearn - Return the AUC after each epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I'm using [TFLearn](http://tflearn.org/) to build a convolutional neural network (CNN). After each epoch, I get values like `accuracy` and `loss` returned for instance.

I was able to find the AUC value after *all* the epochs have run. I'm however interested in the AUC value after *each* epoch. Thus, is there a way to return the AUC value after each epoch?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe TFLearn was incorporated into TensorFlow as tf.contrib.learn some time ago, and has since been expanded significantly. Within tf.contrib.learn, you can easily get AUC reported by adding tf.metrics.auc to the eval_metric_ops returned by your Estimator.

Comment: TFLearn is _not_ the same as `tf.contrib.learn` (which now mostly lives in `tf.estimator`).